# Sending Javascript from node express to an angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to write a common javascript end point for utility methods that would be shared across client & server.

I've read around but I'm struggling to grasp the concepts.

I was thinking, of maybe sending it up as a string and using eval? I'm not sure what the best practice is for this.

So far I've got:

**Client side service that needs scripts.**

```
angular.module('passionForgeApp').service('Utils', function ()
{
    //TODO Load these from the server side utlity module.
}
```

**Node Utility export**

```
'use strict';

var Utility = function(){};

Utility.isASCII = function (str) {
    return /^[\x00-\x7F]*$/.test(str);
};

Utility.isAlphaNumeric = function(str) {
    var code, i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) && // numeric (0-9)
        !(code > 64 && code < 91) && // upper alpha (A-Z)
        !(code > 96 && code < 123)) { // lower alpha (a-z)
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

module.exports = Utility;
```

**Node Express endpoint**
This is where I'm lost.

```
//TODO Bad path.
var utility = require('./../../components/utility');

// Gets a list of Commonjss
exports.utility = function(req, res) {


    //send utility????
    //Stuck here, sends {} to browser.

    res.json(utility);

};
```

**EDIT**

As requested, posted browserify script.

This is being loaded by the browser I can see in the network logs.

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var Utility = function(){};

Utility.isASCII = function (str) {
    return /^[\x00-\xFF]*$/.test(str);
};

Utility.isAlphaNumeric = function(str) {
    var code, i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) && // numeric (0-9)
        !(code > 64 && code < 91) && // upper alpha (A-Z)
        !(code > 96 && code < 123)) { // lower alpha (a-z)
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

module.exports = Utility;

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

My problem is that I don't know how to use it.

In my controller I tried, `console.log(Utility);`
Then I tried require('Utility').

Nothing, undefined. :-/

**Edit**

[Full implementation of bundling shared server side code to client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372877/how-to-bundle-multiple-javascript-libraries-with-browserify#answer-34373341)

Comment: you need to use angular's $http service with the get and post methods to utilize your utilities in the client.

Comment: You need to expose your utility with the --s option. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your folder structure

```
/ root
    / client
        - client.js
    / server
        - server.js
    / shared
        - utility.js
```

In your server (node.js), you "require" files like this

```
var server = require('server.js');
var utility = require('utility.js');
```

In your browser, you require files like this

```
<script src="client.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Node.js has a different module system than the browser. The principal ones are [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) and CommonJS (node's `require()`), and they are not compatible with each other.

Browserify is a utility that will convert a CommonJS or RequireJS module to be browser-compatible (Otherwise it's not). In other words, it will "bundle" all the files that are ever required() by a file (recursively), and bundle them all into a single file, usable by the browser.

So, if you want to be able to use the same file in node.js and the browser, you start by coding it (node.js style) with require()s if you wish.

```
// File utility.js
var a = require('lodash')
var b = require('myotherlib')
module.exports.a = function(a){ } //etc.
```

You can use it in node

```
var utility = require('utility.js');
```

Then, you use the browserify utility on it.

```
browserify utility.js -o utility-bundled.js
```

Then, you can use it in your browser !

```
<script src="utility-bundled.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="controllers.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Browserify "browserifies" modules to be usable in the browser, because otherwise they're not.

-- EDIT 1

This will make your utility library in the "global". Though, if you want to be able to "import" it with this syntax :

```
angular.module('passionForgeApp').service('Utils', function ()
{
    //TODO Load these from the server side utlity module.
}
```

You can set up [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad). It's a very good library for defining lazy-loaded external files.

"lazy-load" it, meaning that it will only download the library when you will explicitly ask for it.

If you are using this approach, you can remove the

```
<script src="utility-bundled.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

From your index.html. And you must set up ocLazyLoad

```
angular.module('app', ['oc.lazyLoad']).config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', function($ocLazyLoadProvider) {
  $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    modules : [{
        name : 'Utility',
        files : ['utility-bundled.js']
    }]
  });
}]);
```

Then you can use it in the modules that need it, in a lazy-loaded fashion

```
angular.module('MyController', ['$ocLazyLoad', function(ocLazyLoad){
    ocLazyLoad.load('Utility');
}]
```

Comment: How do I actually use the model though, once I've included it. ```console.log(Utility);``` is undefined. (I included the script and it's working nicely)

Comment: Can you post both your html and utility-bundled.js

Comment: Two questions ? You are having problem using it in the browser of in node ? If in the browser, did you include the <script src="utility-bundled.js" type="text/javascript"/> in your .html file ?

Comment: Yes I did but there's a lack of documentation on http://browserify.org/ on how to actually use the script client side.

Comment: Can you find either the module or it's functions (isAlphaNumeric, ...) if you do console.log(this) ?

Comment: I'm calling ```Utility.isAlphaNumeric('test');``` ```Uncaught ReferenceError: Utility is not defined```

Comment: try console.log(require('Utility'));

Comment: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined```

Comment: so in your html you have <script src="utility-bundled.js"/><script type="text/javascript>var utility = require('./utility.js'); console.log(utility)</script> ?

Comment: Yep it's loading the script but it says ```Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined``` with you're example.

Comment: Put in the result of console.dir(this)

Comment: Use this browserify script.js --standalone 'Utility' -o utility-bundled.js and to access your lib use window.Utility

Comment: Did that work for you using the standalone mode and window.utility?

Comment: That works perfect, thanks so much for you're help. Although I will have window pollution, this is just a small project.

Comment: This work for one file, but how do i use it with multiple ones? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372877/how-do-i-use-browserify-in-the-browser

Answer (score 4):

IMO it does not have to be that hard. If you are using browserify or a bundler for your front end you can do this. It might be a pain to set up at first but it's worth it.

**project structure**

```
/client
    main.js
    /components
        /utility
            utility.module.js

/server
    controller.js

/utilities <- put your code that is shared between server/client here
    Utility.js
```

**client/components/utility/utility.module.js**

```
module.exports = angular
                    .module("app.utility")
                    .factory("Utility", require(__dirname + "/../../utilities/Utility.js");
```

**utilities/Utility.js**

```
module.exports = {
    toASCII: function() { //do stuff in angular and express }
};
```

**client/main.js (you need to require all your components here, this is your browserify entry point)**

```
require("angular")
    .module("app" [
        "app.utility"
    ]);

    require( <% path to utility.module.js %>);
```

**server/controller.js (you can use your module as would be expected)**

```
var util = require( <% path to Utility.js %>);
util.toASCII(); //do something
```

Comment: Looks slightly complicated as I'm unclear as to what browserify is doing?

Comment: You're basically replacing `require()` with the code you want. In a simple sense it's a project-wide variable that refers to specific files. Bundlers lets you share code between parts of your project, and as a result, keeps your code modular and DRY.

Comment: Do I have to run browserfy each time? What if my code is dynamic?

Comment: If you are using gulp or grunt you can set up a watch so that browserify will work on your entire codebase everytime you make a change to any file. There's lots of tutorials on how to get a build set up quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, trying to implement it now :-)

Comment: How would I bind this to the service instead of including it?

Answer (score 1):

One other way to do this is to write your utility module in node and use browserify to make it runnable on node or the browser.

Browserify will add code at the beginning of your file to check if there is a module.exports object or a window object. It will then make sure that when the code runs the require statements, and the module.exports work.

With your code browserified, you could use the utility functions on a browser by including them in your html script tags.

This should be safer than using eval().

### Update

I made an example. I added a requirement for underscore and moment just to show require statements work. You don't need them though.

Make a file called myUtility.js and add this

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var moment = require('moment');

function now (format) {
    var time;
    var dFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a';
    format = format || dFormat;

    try {
        time = 'TIME:\t' + moment().format(format);
    }catch (err) {
        time = 'TIME:\t' + moment().format(dFormat);
    }finally{
        return time;
    }

}

function isAlphaNumeric(str) {
    var code, i, len;
    return _.every(str, function (letter, i) {
        code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        console.log('code: ' + code);
        if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) && // numeric (0-9)
        !(code > 64 && code < 91) && // upper alpha (A-Z)
        !(code > 96 && code < 123)) { // lower alpha (a-z)
            return false;
        }
    });
}

var myutil = {
    now: now,
    isAlphaNumeric: isAlphaNumeric,
};

module.exports = myutil;
```

run these commands:

```
npm install browserify
npm install underscore
npm install moment
browserify myUtility.js --s myutil -o myutil.js
```

The browserify command above makes myutil.js. Add this to your index.html

```
<script src="/path/to/myutil.js"></script>
```

Add this in your controller and log into your page and check the console output:

```
console.log(myutil)
var isAlphaNumeric = myutil.isAlphaNumeric;
console.log('try cat: ' + isAlphaNumeric('cat'));
console.log('try 123cat123: ' + isAlphaNumeric('123cat123'));
console.log('try ca?t: ' + isAlphaNumeric('ca?t'));
```

The output shows you are using your function now in the browser with module exports and require statements in the file.

Also the ascii codes appear to need adjustment. I believe you want to check if the letter is in any of the ranges with || instead of &&.

```
TIME:   2015-12-18 05:13:00 pm
code: 99
try cat: false
code: 49
try 123cat123: false
code: 99
try ca?t: false
```

When I browserified your function and added it to index.html, I got the incorrect answers in the console. Changing the character logic fixed it so that if the code is not in any of the groups it does not return true:

```
if (
    (code > 47 && code < 58) || // numeric (0-9)   false to true
    (code > 64 && code < 91) || // upper alpha (A-Z) false to true
    (code > 96 && code < 123)   // lower alpha (a-z)
) { 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example? Thanks for replying.

Comment: I added  an example of using browserify for only your module. You do not have to browserify your whole app. Browserify does not expose a variable for your utility by default. So a command like "browserify file -o file2" will not work. You can use the --s option to globally expose your utility object. I updated my response to show how to do it.