# How to include a utility lib in an AngularJS app using Browserify?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, browserify

I have a large AngularJS/Express app where I'd like to begin sharing code between client and server, mainly small utility libraries, e.g:

```
// Name: utilities.js

module.exports.testUtilities = function () {
    console.log('testUtilities: Hello world!');
};
```

I'm now trying to set up **Browserify** using `grunt-browserify`:

```
// Name: Gruntfile.js

browserify: {
    client: {
        src: ['crossplatform/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'app/scripts/crossplatformBrowserify.js'
    }
},
```

I successfully build a `crossplatformBundle.js` which I include in my `index.html`.

But I fail at accessing my Browserified code from the AngularJS client:

```
// Name: MyAngularController.js

var utilities = require('./utilities');
utilities.testUtilities();
```

Error message: `require is undefined`.

I see many Browserify questions where the answer is to bundle up ALL the client-side scripts, but I'd rather avoid that if I can, since I want separate JS files in development mode.

Thankful for any tips I can get!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to define a “standalone” bundle for Browserify:

```
browserify: {
    client: {
        src: ['crossplatform/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'app/scripts/crossplatform.js',
        options: {
            browserifyOptions: {
                standalone: 'crossplatform'
            },
        }
    }
},
```

...which allows me to call the method with `window.crossplatform.testUtilities()` in the browser.

**Update:** see [this thread for more examples of how to bundle multiple libraries/modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372877/how-to-bundle-multiple-javascript-libraries-with-browserify).